# Managing credentials to run as a different user on remote system using PowerShell

Tags: security, powershell, remote-access

I need to get the environment variable settings on a remote machine.

The remote machine runs applications under a service account. `SA123`

If I can connect to the remote machine with my user account, `USER123`, it will not have the environment variables that the `SA123` account uses.

I want to run `Invoke-Command` on the remote machine as the `SA123` account. I do not want to know the `SA123` account password.

What are acceptable ways to manage the `SA123` account credentials that would be acceptable to SECOPS people?

I would ask this on https://stackoverflow.com/, but would probably be run off because it is asking for opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a remote session without knowing/using the credentials which exist on the target.

Set up a scheduled tasked to run on that remote system and report back to you on completion.

See the information options from this link.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27run+scheduled+task+using+a+service+account%27&t=h_&ia=web